# SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(query) - Multiple SQL commands inside the onCreate() method not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am new to android. I haven't worked with SQLite DBs before.
I think this is a very basic question, but I am unable to find the solution.

The code is here (assume declarations)

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + FORMULA + "("
            + CAT_CD + " TEXT ," + S_CAT_CD + " TEXT, PRIMARY 
 KEY(CAT_CD,S_CAT_CD))";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);

    String CREATE_CAT_DESC_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ FORMULA_CAT_DESC + "
("+CAT_CD+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "+ DESC +" TEXT ) ";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CAT_DESC_TABLE);

    String CREATE_CURRENCY_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+ VI_CURRENCY + "("+ 
CURRENCY_CD +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "+ CURRENCY_SIGN +" TEXT ) ";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CURRENCY_TABLE);

   String query=  "INSERT INTO "+ VI_CURRENCY +" ("+CURRENCY_CD +", 
"+CURRENCY_SIGN+ ") VALUES " +
            "('INR', '₹'), " +
            " ('USD','$') " +
            "('JPY','¥') ";
    db.execSQL(query);
 }
```

The first three commands execute successfully, while by executing the insert command,  SQLite throws an exeption.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: You are trying to insert multiple rows by running a single SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a sql statement for each record

```
String query1 =  "INSERT INTO " + VI_CURRENCY + " (" + CURRENCY_CD + ", " + CURRENCY_SIGN + ") VALUES " + "('INR', '₹')" ;

String query2 =  "INSERT INTO " + VI_CURRENCY + " (" + CURRENCY_CD + ", " + CURRENCY_SIGN + ") VALUES " + "('USD','$')" ;

String query3 =  "INSERT INTO " + VI_CURRENCY + " (" + CURRENCY_CD + ", " + CURRENCY_SIGN + ") VALUES " + "('JPY','¥')" ;

db.execSQL(query1);
db.execSQL(query2);
db.execSQL(query3);
```

Or insert multiple values in one statement, with the correct sintax it would be like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO " + VI_CURRENCY + " (" + CURRENCY_CD + ", " + CURRENCY_SIGN + ") VALUES " +
             "('INR', '₹'), " +
             "('USD','$'), " +
             "('JPY','¥')";
db.execSQL(query);
```

For more information visit [SqlLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/)

Comment: I want to insert hundreds of records So should I write hundreds of queries?   I think this is not a good solution.

Comment: I updated the answer, you had a syntax error

Comment: Ohh..thank you. Now Query is working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, writing operation is slow, So in your case, if you have hundreds of data, you can use transactions in SQLite database.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for(/*your loop*/) {
        String query =  /*your query*/

        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

For more detail, Please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()), official doc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple records, then you should take data in hashmap object in key value pair. Use iterator on the same and insert data in table.

```
        Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("INR","₹");
        myMap.put("USD","$");
        myMap.put("JPY","¥");


 Iterator it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
      String query1 =  "INSERT INTO " + VI_CURRENCY + " (" + CURRENCY_CD + ", " + CURRENCY_SIGN + ") VALUES " + "("+ pair.getKey()+ "," + pair.getvalue()+)" ;
    db.execSQL(query1);
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```